# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I try several solutions but nothing does,

I only loop on my routes but I still have this error

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.
    in Route (at Auth.js:14)
    in Auth (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at App.js:31)
    in Route (at App.js:31)
    in Switch (at App.js:29)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:27)
    in Provider (at App.js:26)
    in App (at src/index.js:5)

```
// Auth.js
...
getRoutes = routes => {
    return routes.map((rte, key) => {
      if (rte.layout === "/auth") {
        return (
          <Route
            path={rte.layout + rte.path}
            component={rte.component}
            key={key}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };
...

// App.js
...
<Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
            <Route path="/auth" render={props => <AuthLayout {...props} />} />
            <Redirect from="/" to="/auth/login" />
          </Switch>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
...
```

Comment: show what you have passed to `getRoutes` function

Comment: It looks like `rte.component` might not be what the `<Route>` component is expecting. Could you please show us what `rte.component` is?

Comment: Hi, I passed this in routes file >>                                                                              `var routes = [ { path: "/index", name: "Home", icon: "ni ni-home text-white", component: Index, layout: "/admin" }, { path: "/new-user", name: "User", icon: "ni ni-user text-white", component: userComponent, layout: "/auth", }, .... ]`